# C++ get arguments from URL scheme

Tags: c++

I have a url scheme myapp://123456 (123456 it is a dynamic value) calling an exe file from a webapp. The exe contain the code below. I don't have any experience on C++, VB or other desktop language, i need to pass dynamically the value coming from url where there is hardcoded pippo but i am not able to do it. On google i found Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() that work fine but it is C# and not working on C++ Can someone help me? Thanks

```
CDdeLauncherDlg::CDdeLauncherDlg(CWnd *pParent )
    : CDialog(CDdeLauncherDlg::IDD, pParent)
{


   //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CDdeLauncherDlg)
   m_connect = FALSE;
   m_param1 = 50;
   m_param2 = 50;
   m_param3 = 50;
   m_param4 = 50;
   m_appName = _T("GINCOBILOBA");
   m_appExe = m_appName + "1"; // num. sessione
   m_pathName = _T("");
   m_scriptPath = _T("");
   m_code = _T("pippo");

   //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
   // Note that LoadIcon does not require a subsequent DestroyIcon in Win32
   m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);

   m_pConv = NULL;
   m_iconized = false;
   m_isOpen = false; // APP aperta

   this->Connect();
}
```

this is the windows registry url scheme:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Myapp]
@="URL:Myapp Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Myapp\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Myapp\\Myapp.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Myapp\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Myapp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Myapp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Myapp\\Myapp.exe\" \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\" \"%5\" \"%6\" \"%7\" \"%8\" \"%9\""
```

Comment: `_T("123456")`? You might need to explain your problem in more detail

Comment: That depends on how you actually registered the uri scheme. it could be passed by DDE, command line, etc... You'll at least have to provide [how you registered the URI scheme in the windows registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), otherwise it'll be hard to answer.

Comment: *"i need to pass the value 123456 where there is pippo"* -- That looks like a straight-forward requirement. Did you try it? Just put the value `"123456"` where there is `"pippo"`? What was the result?

Comment: @Turtlefight i have registered the url schema in the window registry, from a web app i call the url schema with a dynamic value and i need to pass it to the exe file, this exe file through DDE pass it to a third part desktop application. I have found on google environment.getcommandlineargs() that work fine on C# but i'm not able to make it work on this C++ code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably, in the case of a C++ application, there should be a main function, something like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
   // ...
}
```

To read the arguments, just read the `argv` parameter, where an index is reserved for each argument, to check the number of arguments just use the `argc` parameter.

To test, just find this function in your code and implement a way to print the value of these parameters (using `std::cout`, for example) and start the application using the terminal in your application's executable folder and type this:

```
./YourApplication.exe "Hello World!"
```

In your case, when you call the application through a browser, for example, the arguments after `://` are ignored. Somehow the browser doesn't pass the arguments when the application is called.